un-maximize windows using pygetwindow
I have a python project where i want to resize the windows i get with title and make a little animation using sine wave. The animation first resizes the window and centers it to the screen and then starts changing its 'y' position using math.sine() this works really good but there is a problem. If the window is maximized, then the pygetwindow package can't resize or change the position of the window. I can maximize a window or check if it is maximized but i can't un-maximize the window. Is there any method for doing this.
I don't want to use libraries such as pyautogui to just perform a click to the maximize button or keyboard to press any short cut for the job. I want a true pygetwindow command to make the window.maximized = false.
Thanks

As per the documentation, the simple minimize() function is shown:
>>> import pygetwindow as gw
>>> notepadWindow = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Untitled')[0]
>>> notepadWindow.isMaximized
False
>>> notepadWindow.maximize()
>>> notepadWindow.isMaximized
True
>>> notepadWindow.restore()
>>> notepadWindow.minimize()
>>> notepadWindow.restore()
>>> notepadWindow.activate()
>>> notepadWindow.resize(10, 10) # increase by 10, 10
>>> notepadWindow.resizeTo(100, 100) # set size to 100x100
>>> notepadWindow.move(10, 10) # move 10 pixels right and 10 down
>>> notepadWindow.moveTo(10, 10) # move window to 10, 10
>>> notepadWindow.size
(132, 100)
>>> notepadWindow.width
132
>>> notepadWindow.height
100
>>> notepadWindow.topleft
(10, 10)
>>> notepadWindow.top
10
>>> notepadWindow.left
10
>>> notepadWindow.bottomright
(142, 110)
>>> notepadWindow.close()

But you don't even need the documentation, simply check the python packaging index to see this code. However, I'd also like to point out that there's always other options like win32gui or win32com.client if you don't want to use pygetwindow.
